# SEO Lite: "extra" tags in EE 4

Tags: seo, seo-lite, ee4

I am trying to get the {extra:...} tags to work ([per the docs](http://wedoaddons.com/seo-lite/configuration#config-file-settings)) in EE4 but am having no luck.

In my config.php file, I have the following:

```
$config['seolite_tab_title'] = 'SEO';
// Pull additional info for SEO Lite
// channel_id => array(field_id => tag_name)
$config['seolite_extra'] = array(
  // home channel:
  '5' => array(
    'robots' => array(
      'field_id' => 62,
      'field_type' => 'text'
    )
  ),
);
```

The SEO Lite template (in the CP) is as follows:

```
<title>{title}</title>
<meta name='description' content='{meta_description}'>
<link rel='canonical' href='{canonical_url}'>
<meta name="robots" content="{extra:robots}">
```

The output is fine for the first three lines, but the robots tag outputs like so:

```
<meta name="robots" content="">
```

On the Devot:ee site, someone noted that the extra tags don't work in EE4. Is this correct? If so, does anyone have a workaround/fix (besides just using the field natively with EE code/syntax)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is looking for the answer to this - it has been fixed in v1.5.5 which can be downloaded here: https://github.com/bjornbjorn/SEO-Lite/releases

Changelog: http://wedoaddons.com/seo-lite/changelog

Comment: Any chance to make this work also on EE5? I'm experiencing the same problem with a 5.x installation. @Bjørn